# Trying to get 3 HTML elements on the same line

Tags: asp.net

I have searched this site looking for the answer and found similar things, but nothing that stood out as the answer, probably due to my lack of experience with this.  I am using the JQuery slider below a table and the slider is required to be in its own div.  I am trying to get the 'min' label to show to the left of the slider and the 'max' to the right, all 3 elements on the same line.  As the code shows below, it places each element on its own line and I do understand why that is, too.

However, I have tried floating left, placing each in its own div, and placing all 3 in one div.  I have tried a combination of those as well.  I can't get it and each experiment I try results in a look that makes no logical sense to me.

What am I missing?  Thanks for any help :)

```
<label id="min">0</label>
<div id="slider" style="width:450px"></div>
<label id="max">200</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using CSS floats.

```
<style>
    #mySlider label, #mySlider div {float: left;)
</style>    
<div id="mySlider">
    <label id="min">0</label> 
    <div id="slider" style="width:450px">(slider)</div> 
    <label id="max">200</label> 
</div>    
​
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eRUgf/)

Comment: Thanks - this worked.  And thanks for the JS Fiddle link, too.

Answer (score 1):

Add some css:

```
#min,#max,#slide {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the CSS

```
#min, #max, #slider {
display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;
}
```

Which will ensure the elements are all stacked next to each other instead of one per line.

You may find this interesting reading on floats vs inline-block too http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block

Comment: Thank you for the article...I am still tweaking my code to get it to look just right and I see the quirks and touchiness already.